# clunking/popping/crackling noise at low speed

Tags: noise, wheels, suspension, mazda-3

Does anybody know what could cause this clunking/popping/crackling noise only at low speeds when hitting a rougher surface- bumps, dips, stone roads (under 10-15 MPH) ?
The position of the steering wheel doesn’t matter, it happens either with wheels straight or turned.
The noise can be heard on both sides(driver and passager
I checked: coilovers preload(tried 5 mm preload and 0 preload), top nut of the strut, greased with lithium grease spray the coilovers bearings, cv axeles.
I replaced: all engine mounts, end tie rods, sway bar endlinks, lower control arms, sway bar bushings
I re torqued everything.

I want to mention that everthing replaced above are ~ 6 months old or newer .

Here is a video of the noise : https://m.imgur.com/a/v2TtQm1#qJVm3QX

The car is a Mazda 3 BK(1st gen)

TIA

Answer (score 1):

It's likely the struts, springs and some related parts (strut bearings, mounting plates, coil spring protectors).  See the reply in [this post](https://www.mazda3revolution.com/threads/please-help-clunking-noise-in-front-end.25802/page-2) from "444rose" at the top.